# Error in ionic installation

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I am installing ionic via sudo npm install ionic -g

and getting the following error

> ```
> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/ionic -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic
>
> > node-sass@3.4.2 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/node-sass
> > node scripts/install.js
>
>
> module.js:340
>     throw err;
>           ^
> Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:902:3
> npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
> npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.2/bin/npm" "install" "ionic" "-g"
> npm ERR! node v4.2.2
> npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 8
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
> ```

The issue is also listed in ionic forums: - https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/installing-ionic-not-successful-solved/36050/7

I have tried changing node, npm, cordova versions multiple times but every time I get this error so I guess this has nothing to do with versions.
Also at some places it was mentioned that installing ionic from root might help so I have done that also.

Kindly help me figure out this one. Thanks

Comment: are you following this http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ step by step.

Comment: I have commented the error on your answer

Comment: what system you are using ubuntu or windows or mac

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Comment: then the tutorial that i have posted in my answer should work perfectly, may be the error you are facing is because what you have tried previously so try to uninstall all and the try my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109668/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-yatin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to install ionic-framework follow in [Nic-raboy bolg](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/) here.

```
chmod 775 ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh
sudo ./ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh
```

Download the ubuntu_ionic_installer.sh from the `**download a convenient shell script**` which is provided in the blog and then follow the steps and sit back and relax.

Comment: tried it with the script as well, got the following error  /root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/ionic -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/lib/node_modules/ionic/bin/ionic

> node-sass@3.4.2 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
 at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
 at startup (node.js:129:16)
 at node.js:814:3
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/lib
`-- (empty)npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v5.10.1/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Comment: npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js

Comment: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-sass
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1

Comment: removed everything, even formatted my system and then the script worked like magic. Thanks.