# Ionic installation a file is always missing

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed node, cordova 6.1.1, python 2.7.

I've been trying to install ionic for the past 3 hours on windows, but I get error after error. A file is always missing. I've uninstalled it a couple of times, I even deleted the whole node_modules inside npm, but nothing will make it work. How can I solve this?

[image: ionic]

Comment: try cleaning npm cache: `npm cache clean` and installing ionic again

Comment: @PrashantGhimire it says operation not permitted

Comment: Oh, yes ... I'll run now the ionic installation again and get back to you

Comment: @PrashantGhimire same error.

Comment: This sucks, but I would try reinstalling node/npm...

Comment: I've never used it. I did a fresh installation just for installing ionic. I guess I'll reinstall it now..

Comment: Now I get a node sass error + visual studio + a lot more. I don't get this installer. I'll install visualt studio community now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112453/discussion-between-prashant-ghimire-and-bogdan-daniel).

Comment: To install ionic here is a simple step that i have posted in other stack question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498317/error-in-ionic-installation/36740200#36740200

Answer (score 0):

The first 4 times I used the latest version of node.js v6.2.0. To make it work I uninstalled it and used v4.4.4 LTS. If you're having the same problem, I hope this helps.