# how to Install ionic framework in fresh ubuntu 16.04? do we need android studio for ionic framework?

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, ant, ionic-framework

I have installed Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). I want to install Ionic framework to Build an hybrid application. Do i need Android Studio, apache ant and other dependences? Please guide me how to install ionic frame work step by step I am NOOB. Please guide me in details.
I am Getting this error after installing ionic frame work.

> saqib@saqib-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ nodejs --version
>   
> v4.2.6
>   saqib@saqib-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ cordova --version
>   6.2.0
>   saqib@saqib-HP-ProBook-4530s:~$ ionic --version
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/logging.js:9
>       new (winston.transports.Console)({
>                              ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'Console' of undefined
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/logging.js:9:28)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/ionic-app-lib/lib/info.js:9:15)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)

Comment: i have answered this question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498317/error-in-ionic-installation/36740200#36740200 easy to install

Comment: Thanks for your reply. let me check your answer.