# Error install ionic framework through npm

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Cannot install ionic

```
 76 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
    77 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "ionic" "-g"
    78 error node v6.2.2
    79 error npm  v3.9.5
    80 error shasum check failed for C:\Users\iCom\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-6100-6eb8c472\registry.npmjs.org\ionic\-\ionic-1.7.16.tgz
    80 error Expected: aeff62ee70b10b1563d85b9d4ea7005640bbc584
    80 error Actual:   712351e02cbbe0cfc95135424a09d110f649add5
    80 error From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/ionic/-/ionic-1.7.16.tgz
    81 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
    81 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
    82 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

i try many time, it is cannot install

Comment: try to install like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36498317/error-in-ionic-installation/36740200#36740200

Comment: run cmd as administrator and then try

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning cache using `npm cache clean` before running `npm install` again. This worked for me on OSX when I encountered the same error.